# How would I complete this using a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

Let's say I have a list in Python that contains 24 elements. I'm using each element in the list to use in a sentence, for example: (for this example the list contains numbers, but in the real case it contains names, places, etc

```
s = [Steve, 25, Bill, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24]
```

If I needed to write 3 sentences each sentence using elements 1-8 from the list like this:

Sentence 1:

```
It is s[1] degrees outside, my name is s[2]. My friend is s[0].
```

The sentence would go on using elements 1-8, I only used 3 for an example. I need to write three of these sentences and need to use a loop because there could be any amount of sentences needed to write.

The elements go in the same place for each sentence, so in the next sentence it would be:

```
It is s[8] degrees outside, my name is s[9]. My friend is [7].
```

Is there anyway to complete this with a loop? I'm hoping you guys understand my question. The loop gets an index out of range error because I'm running it N times (which in this case is 3)

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please review [ask] and post your code that gives that index out of range error!

Comment: This is the best question I've seen today.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "It is {s[1]} degrees outside, my name is {s[2]}. My friend is {s[0]}."
s = ['Steve', 25, 'Bill', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24]
for g in zip(*[iter(s)]*3):
    print sentence.format(s=g)
```

maybe ... at least